# Play specific sound on list item click

Tags: android, listview, audio, resources

I have this app where I have a listview and I would like to play a sound when an item is clicked. I tried a lot of things but none of them seem to solve my problem.

It's a listview with words, it's translation and a play button, when I click the button I want to play the sound of the specific word. Here I have my adapter and the class used. If someone knows how to answer this question I would be happy ;)

CLASS:

```
public class VB_Itens extends ListActivity {
        private VB_Itens_Adapter adapter;
        private int wordsArrayId, translationsArrayId;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0);

            // Here i populate the list with the words and it's translations from arrays resource

            switch (position) {

            case 0:
                wordsArrayId = R.array.VB_airport_words;
                translationsArrayId = R.array.VB_airport_translations;
                break;
            case 1:
                wordsArrayId = R.array.VB_hotel_words;
                translationsArrayId = R.array.VB_hotel_translations;
                break;
            case 2:
                wordsArrayId = R.array.VB_hospital_words;
                translationsArrayId = R.array.VB_hospital_translations;
                break;
            case 3:
                wordsArrayId = R.array.VB_restaurant_words;
                translationsArrayId = R.array.VB_restaurant_translations;
                break;
            }

            adapter = new VB_Itens_Adapter(this, wordsArrayId, translationsArrayId);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

            // I want to play a specific sound and the item is clicked
            // I don't know how to take these sounds

        }
    }
```

ADAPTER:

```
public class VB_Itens_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Palavra> listaPalavras = new ArrayList<Palavra>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public VB_Itens_Adapter(Context context, int resPalavra, int resTraducao) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        String palavras[] = context.getResources().getStringArray(resPalavra);
        String traducoes[] = context.getResources().getStringArray(resTraducao);

        for (int i = 0; i < palavras.length; i++) {
            Palavra palavra = new Palavra(palavras[i], traducoes[i]);
            listaPalavras.add(palavra);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listaPalavras.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listaPalavras.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vb_itens, null);

        Palavra palavra = listaPalavras.get(position);

        TextView palavraView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.palavra);
        TextView traducaoView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.traducao);

        palavraView.setText(palavra.getPalavra());
        traducaoView.setText(palavra.getTradução());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you get get the 'wordtobetranslated' first then try to get de resource id with `getResources().getIdentifier( "wordtobetranslated" , "raw" , this.class.getPackageName() );`. R.raw.wordtobetranslated. So you can omit a complete switch.

Comment: And how am I supposed to find this raw? Using another switch?

Comment: You don't have to find it anymore then because you have it then. It's equal to R.raw.wordttobetranslated. So no switches anymore.

Comment: Is there any method in the "View" class so i can take the word? like view.gettext()?

Comment: In onListItemClick you have a position parameter. With that parameter 'at hand' you can retrieve the actual word in the same manner as you do now in getView().

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your sounds in mp3 or wave format into the raw folder in the project directory, and then use the following code.

```
final MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
              switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_of_a);
                    mp.start();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_of_b);
                    mp.start();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_of_c);
                    mp.start();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_of_d);
                    mp.start();
                    break;
                }
    }
```

Hope it'll help.

Comment: But if I have too many items on the list, it will be a huge switch :l

Comment: if you have static number of sounds then you have to use this type of solution, or may be you can use an array of all sound's id and then create a loop on position variable and instantiate all the sounds one by one,

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, the `R.raw.example_sound` can be placed in map(`raw`) under `values`, if it does not exist create it yourself

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.example_sound);
mediaPlayer.start()
```

Comment: You should create it under `values` yourself and name it `raw`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create your own 'AccessibilityService 'and use 'TextToSpeech' to provide

spoken feedback for the users click.